# QuickSort breaking

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to parallelize quick sort so I wrote the serial version first with partition and recursive sort on both partitions. This works.. Until sizes of > 100,000 in which case if one of the partitions is too big it goes forever and never finishes. I can't figure out why that is. It will run in 13-15 ms at 100k but then at 120k it will either run at around the same time or just not at all.

For my partition I picked the pivot based on the median of the first, middle, and last elements of the current partition and if they are equal it goes to the last element.

Here's my partition:

```
private static int partition(int low, int high, int[] array){
    //get median of first, last, and middle element in our section
    int lVal, hVal, mVal, pIndex, pVal;
    lVal = array[low];
    hVal = array[high];
    mVal = array[((high-low+1)/2) + low];
    //System.out.println("LOW: " + low + "HIGH: " + high);
    if (lVal < hVal && lVal > mVal || lVal > hVal && lVal < mVal){
        pIndex = low;
        //System.out.println("Picking low index: " + low);
    } else if (hVal < lVal && hVal > mVal || hVal > lVal && hVal < mVal){
        pIndex = high;
        //System.out.println("Picking high index: " + high);
    } else if (mVal < hVal && mVal > lVal || mVal > hVal && mVal < lVal){
        pIndex = (high-low+1)/2+low;
        //System.out.println("Picking middle index: " + ((high-low+1)/2)+low);
    } else {
        pIndex = high;
    }
    pVal = array[pIndex];

    //put pivot at the back of our chunk
    int temp = array[pIndex];
    array[pIndex] = array[high];
    array[high] = temp;
    //printArray();

    //two pointer method.. high and low.. move them and swap if low > pivot and high < pivot
    int left = low;
    int right = high - 1;
    pIndex = 0;

    while (left <= right){
        while(left <= high && array[left] < pVal){
            left++;
        }
        while(right >= low && array[right] > pVal){
            right--;
        }
        //if both elements at the pointers are on the wrong side we swap
        if(left < right){
            temp = array[left];
            array[left] = array[right];
            array[right] = temp;
            left++;
            right--;
            //printArray();
        }
    }
    //need to get pivot from high to where the low pointer ended
    temp = array[left];
    array[left] = array[high];
    array[high] = temp;

    //printArray();
    return left;
}
```

This doesn't seem to take long no matter how many elements there are so I'm not sure if this is the cause or not.

Here is my sort:

```
public static void sort (int low, int high, Comparator c, int[] array){
        if(high - low > 1) {
            int pIndex = partition(low, high, array);

            sort(low, pIndex - 1, c, array);
            sort(pIndex + 1, high, c, array);
        }

}
```

Any ideas on why this is freezing up at a certain point would be fantastic. I ran another type of partition I found on the internet and it ran fine at any size I gave it but I want to know what is wrong with this. Here is my unit test I'm using to test it.

```
@Test
public void testSortStandard() throws Exception {
    int size = 100000;
    //test randoms to 10000
    int[] a = new int[size];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        a[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    QuickSort.sort(0, a.length-1, null, a);

    testIsSorted(a);
}
```

It just continues to run and run and run. I have a feeling it is just partitioning things over and over and over again wastefully.

Comment: What this behavior tells me is that a relatively unprobable bug appears when dealing with sizes large enough to make the bug appear. I would be curious to find out if it happens on smaller sizes if you keep calling quicksort thousands of times in a loop but with a much smaller input so as to increase the chance of falling on that bug.

Comment: Ya I just made one that calls it on only an array size of 10,000 but it sorts a new array 100 times and if I run it 5-10 times it will break the same way. So thank you for helping me narrow it down to this point at least. Now I just have to find the bug. Not sure what it would be.

Comment: Keep going down in size and increasing frequency until you get a case small enough that you can easily debug. I would recommend that before you call quicksort, you first make a copy of the data being sorted so as to examine it in detail when it fails to sort.

Comment: I just figured out with a new unit test that it is caused by duplicate numbers as I ran a test with all one number as the array and it did the same thing. I thought I had dealt with that but apparently not. I think it occurs when duplicate numbers are in a partition of only 2 or on the borders of the array. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TylerHelmuth If you have a solution to the problem, you should probably post it as an answer so that it's easier for visitors to the site to see what's wrong and how to fix it. :-)